# Installation of "JavaScript GUI Lib" plugin fails in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to install JavaScript GUI Lib plugin on jenkins. I am getting the following errors.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1243)
Failed to load http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/ace-editor/1.1/ace-editor.hpi to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\ace-editor.jpi.tmp
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1250)
```

Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/ace-editor/1.1/ace-editor.hpi (redirected to: http://mirror.serverion.com/jenkins/plugins/ace-editor/1.1/ace-editor.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1284)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1832)"

I checked if I have access to http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/ace-editor/1.1/ace-editor.hpi""using curl. I was able to reach the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. Looks like there was a problem with restart. I downloaded the plugin and restarted Jenkins and installed it explicitly. It is working now.